# Convert array of JSON objects using python

Tags: python, sql, json

I have the following function in python, which is a query:

The output of this is a table.

```
def queryNoScan(start_time_prod,date_object,start_time_scan,date_object_scan):
    query_basictable = """
    SELECT t1.Machine, t1.Production, t2.Scanned, (t1.Production-t2.Scanned) as Delta
        FROM
         (SELECT MCH_CODE as Machine, COUNT(CODE) AS Production
                FROM table1
                        WHERE CODE = 'PROD' AND SUBCODE = 'MACH'  
                        AND EVS_START  between '%s'and '%s' and PP_CODE ='A'
                        GROUP BY MCH_CODE) t1 
        INNER JOIN
         (SELECT MCH_CODE as Machine,  COUNT(BARCODE) AS Scanned
                FROM table2
                        WHERE TRC_TIMESTAMP between '%s'and '%s' AND PP_CODE ='A'
                        GROUP BY MCH_CODE) t2 ON t1.Machine=t2.Machine
                        ORDER BY Delta desc
    """ %(start_time_prod,date_object,start_time_scan,date_object_scan)

    scan_data = pd.read_sql(sql=query_basictable, con=engine)

    return scan_data
```

How can I convert the output of this function to a JSON of strings which I will passed them later in a front end.
Like: "machine": {"Machine2": 14317, etc etc

Comment: Do *not* use string formatting operations to build a SQL query.

Comment: Did you try: `    return scan_data.to_json()`?

Comment: In case @chepner wasn't clear, this is what you should do: http://bobby-tables.com/python.html

Comment: Hello @JanZeiseweis. Thank you so much. I've used your method but now I am getting the result messed out like this: {"Machine":{"0":"Machine","1":"Machine2"}} . How can I get a nice look like Machine 1 and under Machine 2

Comment: Also @JanZeiseweis please press answer the question so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) method from pandas to convert your dataframe into a json string. In the documentation you can also find some helpful examples.

And please don't ignore the comment from chepner since he's right. You should not use the string formatting operation to generate SQL queries.

Instead use the params argument of the [`read_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) method:

```
def queryNoScan(start_time_prod, date_object, start_time_scan, date_object_scan):
    query_basictable = """
    SELECT t1.Machine, t1.Production, t2.Scanned, (t1.Production-t2.Scanned) as Delta
        FROM
         (SELECT MCH_CODE as Machine, COUNT(CODE) AS Production
                FROM table1
                        WHERE CODE = 'PROD' AND SUBCODE = 'MACH'  
                        AND EVS_START  between %s and %s and PP_CODE ='A'
                        GROUP BY MCH_CODE) t1 
        INNER JOIN
         (SELECT MCH_CODE as Machine,  COUNT(BARCODE) AS Scanned
                FROM table2
                        WHERE TRC_TIMESTAMP between %s and %s AND PP_CODE ='A'
                        GROUP BY MCH_CODE) t2 ON t1.Machine=t2.Machine
                        ORDER BY Delta desc
    """ 
    params = (start_time_prod, date_object, start_time_scan, date_object_scan)

    scan_data = pd.read_sql(sql=query_basictable, con=engine, params=params)

    return scan_data.to_json()
```